# How can I create a legend for a Heat Map when I don't want to show the full range of colors?

Tags: plotting, legending

I produce a heat map with legend with the code shown below

```
Needs["PlotLegends`"]

mydata = Table[2 + Sin[x y/5.], {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}];

ShowLegend[
   MatrixPlot[mydata, 
       Mesh -> True, ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap",
       FrameTicks -> None, MeshStyle -> Thin, 
       FrameStyle -> AbsoluteThickness[0], 
       PlotRangePadding -> 0.0
   ], 
  {ColorData["TemperatureMap"][1 - #1] &, 4, 
   ToString[NumberForm[Max[mydata], 4]], "", 
   LegendPosition -> {1.1, -0.8}, LegendSize -> {.25, 0.5}, 
   LegendShadow -> None
  }
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The data used to generate the meat map does not contain negative values, so the plotted heat map only shows a color range from white to red. But when I plot the legend, the color range shown is from blue to red. How can I adjust the legend's color range to the data. Alternatively, how can I manually adjust the labelling in the legend so as to label the red area with `Max[mydata]`, add something like "<0" to the blue area and also attach a label to other colors? Many thanks for anyone's help!

Comment: hello @pjk and welcome to Mathematica.Stackexchange. Could you please complete your post with the definition of xtix ytix?

Comment: hi @chris, sorry, I wanted to delete that, it refers to the data, one can set it FrameTicks->None

Comment: Try `ColorData["TemperatureMap"][.5 + (1 - #1)/2]` in place of `ColorData["TemperatureMap1 - #1]`.

Comment: @kguler: Many thanks that works. Can you also tell me what I would have to change if I want everything from white to blue (i.e. into the negatives)? Many thanks pjk

Comment: @kguler, many thanks I got it.

Comment: @kguler It is a short answer, but still an answer. I suggest you use this as an official answer. I hate questions with zero answers that actually are solved in comments. Bad for our score.

Comment: @Sjoerd,  I found the remaining part of the question (adding labels to all colors in the legend) quite challenging with `PlotLegends`, and was hoping that someone would come up with the appropriate settings for a complete answer. Just posted an answer ... but, I am sure there is an easier solution to OP's problem without using `PlotLegends`.

Answer (score 3):

An alternative to the solution suggested by kguler in comments would be to stretch the color range used in the plot by circumventing `MatrixPlot`'s own `ColorFunctionScaling`:

```
ShowLegend[
   MatrixPlot[mydata, 
       Mesh -> True, 
       ColorFunctionScaling -> False,
       ColorFunction -> (ColorData["TemperatureMap"][Rescale[#, {Min[mydata], Max[mydata]}]] &),
       FrameTicks -> None, MeshStyle -> Thin, 
       FrameStyle -> AbsoluteThickness[0], 
       PlotRangePadding -> 0.0
   ], 
  {ColorData["TemperatureMap"][1 - #1] &, 4, 
   ToString[NumberForm[Max[mydata], 4]], ToString[NumberForm[Min[mydata], 4]], 
   LegendPosition -> {1.1, -0.8}, LegendSize -> {.25, 0.5}, 
   LegendShadow -> None
  }
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 1):

To get the color range in the legend to match that in the plot, replace `ColorData["TemperatureMap"][1 - #1]&` in the original code  with

```
ColorData["TemperatureMap"][.5 + (1 - #1)/2]&
```

To add additional labels to the legend can prove painful if you need more than the two extreme labels.

Using

```
Needs["PlotLegends`"]

mydata = Table[2 + Sin[x y/5.], {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}];
mplt = MatrixPlot[mydata, Mesh -> True,
  ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap", FrameTicks -> None, 
  MeshStyle -> Thin,  FrameStyle -> AbsoluteThickness[0], PlotRangePadding -> 0.0, 
  ImageSize -> 400];
```

The settings needed to add a second label at the bottom is straightforward:

```
legendsettings1 = {ColorData["TemperatureMap"][.5 + (1 - #1)/2] &, 4,
  " " <> ToString@NumberForm[Max[Flatten@mydata], {3, 2}],
  " " <> ToString@NumberForm[Min[Flatten@mydata], {3, 2}],
 LegendPosition -> {1.1, -0.8}, LegendSize -> {.25, 0.5},
 LegendBorderSpace -> .2, LegendShadow -> None};
```

The above syntax does not allow more than two labels. To label all colors, after a long trial-and-error series, I could not get anything simpler than the following:

```
 legendsettings2 = {Graphics[{ColorData["TemperatureMap"][.5 + (1 - #1)/2],
   EdgeForm[{Thickness[.2], ColorData["TemperatureMap"][.5 + (1 - #1)/2]}],
   Rectangle[{0.2, -.2}, {.8, 1.}],
   Black, Text[NumberForm[Quantile[Flatten@mydata, 1 - #1], {3, 2}], {2.2, 1/2}]},
   PlotRange -> {{0, 3}, {-.2, 1.1}}] &, 4,
  LegendPosition -> {1.1, -0.8}, LegendSize -> {.3, .5},
  LegendBorderSpace -> .10, LegendShadow -> None};
```

With these two settings,

```
 Row[{ShowLegend[mplt, legendsettings1], ShowLegend[mplt, legendsettings2]}, Spacer[5]]
```

gives

[image]

Comment: Could perhaps use FindDivisions