# Show single legend with approriate color range for a GraphicsGrid

Tags: plotting, graphics, color, legending

I have a GraphicsGrid of MatrixPlots in the range between 0 and 1 and I want to show a single legend for all of the grid with the appropriate color range.

I tried:

```
Row[{GraphicsGrid[
   Table[Graphics[
     MatrixPlot[RandomReal[1, {10, 10}], Frame -> False, 
      FrameTicks -> False, ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap"]], {x, 1,
      10}, {y, 1, 10}]], BarLegend[{"TemperatureMap", {0, 1}}]}]
```

But the legend's color range does not match those of the graphics. Is there an alternative way to generate a legend?

I found two posts with a similar topic, but I'm not sure how to apply this to my data

- [How can I create a legend for a Heat Map when I don't want to show the full range of colors?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/13506/how-can-i-create-a-legend-for-a-heat-map-when-i-dont-want-to-show-the-full-rang)
- [Single Legend for a Table of Plots](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/41835/single-legend-for-a-table-of-plots)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Almost there, you problem is, that ColorFunction automaticly rescales. You can change this with `ColorFunctionScaling -> False`.

So you get:

```
Row[
 {
  GraphicsGrid[
   Table[Graphics[
     MatrixPlot[RandomReal[1, {10, 10}], Frame -> False, 
      FrameTicks -> False, ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap", 
      ColorFunctionScaling -> False]], {x, 1, 10}, {y, 1, 10}]
   ],
  BarLegend[{"TemperatureMap", {0, 1}}]
  }
 ]
```

Which works like intended:

[image]

(Well, i would increase the size of the Graphics, but this can easily done by `ImageSize`-Option)
Like so:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! That works well! I was wondering if there is a way to adapt the color for the legend to the graphics instead of the other way around?

Comment: You could simply define your own colorfunction and apply it inside the graphics and use it for the legend. I recommend, you take a look at `Blend` .

Comment: Great, thank you :)!